# PHP rename array keys in dynamically created array

Tags: php, arrays, web

In my php code I have an array and each key of it starts with `"@a"` character. How can I remove that symbol? I never know what keys exactly I'll get, but I need to delete `"@a"`.

Comment: Have you generated this array from a SimpleXML object? If so, show your code logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a slicker way with an array function and callback, but here's one:

```
$array = array_combine(str_replace('@a', '', array_keys($array)), $array);
```

Comment: Mark Baker asked a question in comments and you didn't show any efforts/attempts to solve it.  I was bored so you got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Strange request - I'd be interested to know why you want to do this? At any rate, something like this should work:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($weirdArray as $key => $value)
{
    $newKey = str_replace('@a', '', $key);
    $newArray[$newKey] = $value;
}
```

For the record there is a decent chance you don't actually need to do this - you should let us know more details.